# Exception Unhandled

Tags: c, exception

In Visual Studio the fscanf gives me this error:

Unhandled exception at 0x6080D4EC (ucrtbased.dll) in Programação Imperativa.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00D0B000.

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>


   struct estrutura
  {
char nome[100];
    float no1;
float no2;
float valor;
  }v1, r1, r2, r3, r4;

int main(void)
{
FILE *circuito;
int x;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
circuito = fopen("circuito.cir", "r");


if (circuito == NULL)
{
    printf("Erro na abertura do ficheiro");
}
else
{
    while ((x = fgetc(circuito)) != '\n');

    fscanf_s(circuito, "%s %f %f %f\n", v1.nome, &v1.no1, &v1.no2, &v1.valor);
    printf("%s %lf %lf %lf \n", v1.nome, v1.no1, v1.no2, v1.valor);

    fscanf_s(circuito, "%s %f %f %f\n", r1.nome, &r1.no1, &r1.no2, &r1.valor);
    printf("%s %f %f %f \n", r1.nome, r1.no1, r1.no2, r1.valor);
}





return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT:  regarding: `printf("Erro na abertura do ficheiro");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  and when the error indication is from a C library function, then should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` properly handles all of this.  After handling an unrecoverable error, then should call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  (from `stdlib.h`)  For one reason, typically a return of 0 indicates 'success', but the code was NOT successful.

Comment: what input are you giving it? how much does it print out?

Answer (score 5):

You are using `fscanf_s` with `%s` specifier incorrectly.

> Unlike `fscanf` ... `fscanf_s` ... requires the buffer size to be
>   specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string
>   control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is
>   passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to
>   the buffer or variable.

Because there is one too few arguments passed, the address passed to accept a value for the final `%f` is undefined.

The compiler should have warned you about the missing buffer size argument.

Comment: The compiler is not required to report errors in varargs. A lot of the time it can't.

Comment: @MadPhysicist OP's Visual Studio warns about this.

Comment: TIL. I mostly use gcc.